# linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic

Tags: package-management, kernel

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and while updating (upgrading) I received an error message:

```
Error: BrokenCount>0.
```

I was searching and trying everything I found here, but the package `linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic` can't be installed.

I also tried deleting the package with the description 'Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32bitX86SMP' but couldn't reinstall it. Reinstalling the OS didn't solve it.

It seems like the problem is, whatever I try this (after typing `apt-get clean`):

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the download directory
```

I just want to get rid of the red warning sign, please help!

Comment: First run `fuser /var/cache/apt/archives/lock` to see whether any process still claims this file. If none does, remove the lockfile: `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock`. Then run `sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. Report whether the warning sign persists.

Comment: Didn't work, but the problem is (don't know how did I forget): 

'This kernel doesn't support a non PAE cpu' 

I can't even access Ubuntu Software Center or install anything now. Is there a way just to remove the sign?

Comment: Do you, by chance, have an Intel Pentium M CPU?

Comment: Ouch! *some* Pentium M processors are not supported by Linux any more...  You *might* get lucky and add the following boot option to your `grub.cfg`: `forcePAE` (after `quiet splash`). Some Pentium M processors *have* PAE extensions, but don't advertise them...  If *that* doesn't help, try buying a Pentium M with PAE extensions (or dismantling one from another PC you find on a scrap heap)

Comment: I couldn't even install Ubuntu without using forcepae, but I don't understand why doesn't it work then?

Comment: @Fabby The third time I tried forcepae it worked! Finally! Thank you!!! (P. S. could you answer the question?)

Comment: @the_Seppi : please read above comments.  As you're the first one to think of Pentium M, I'm giving you the option of answering first (and get the credit) as the *idea* is *worth more* then the execution! If you don't want the answer and credit, just comment "@Fabby: GO!" ;-)

Comment: Toltek: as mentioned before, *the idea is worth more then the execution* so @the_Seppi 's comment just made me think like him and I just gave you a small hand and you did all the work, but the credit was, is and will be the_Seppi's!  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some CPUs of the Intel Pentium M series are a bit strange when it comes to PAE (Physical Address Extension). They don't report their PAE support to the kernel, so the installer may ask you to install the non-PAE version of Ubuntu.

This can be "fixed" (circumvented) by telling the kernel to assume that PAE is supported, even if it can't see it. To do so, you need to add the `forcepae` argument to the boot parameters, which forces the kernel to assume PAE is present and use it.

Open the file `/etc/default/grub` in a root text editor and change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" # May contain other values
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash forcepae"
```

Then save, exit and run `sudo update-grub` to include this into the boot loader. Afterwards reboot.

After a reboot, you should be able to install the kernel update, since the current kernel now reports the presence of PAE, and thus APT now allows the installation of the kernel update.